# How to create bar graph with numeric categories in the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bar graph with an x-axis (length in cm) in groups. What I have is a dataset with 400 individuals and their body lengths. This is a really basic graph but I have trouble finding the correct R commands. (I do not want to create a histogram.)
Here is a dummy dataset.

```
 length = c(6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,23,24,26,27,29,30,31,38,34,35,30,48,50)
```

How do I create a bar graph with counts as categories on the x-axis?
For example; a count from 5 cm – 10 cm is 6, a count from 10 cm – 15 cm is 5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(length = c(6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,23,24,26,27,29,30,31,38,34,35,30,48,50))

plot_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(length_bin = cut(length, c(seq(min(length), max(length)+5, by=5)), right = F, include.lowest = T))
levels(plot_df$length_bin) <- gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)", "", levels(plot_df$length_bin))
levels(plot_df$length_bin) <- gsub(",", "-", levels(plot_df$length_bin))
plot_df %>% 
  group_by(length_bin) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(length_bin, count)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to change the x-axis ticks to 6-11 instead of [6,11)?

Comment: @Rnoobie isn't this just a histogram though? I thought you didn't want a histogram?

Comment: From my understanding histograms are for non-discrete data. I wanted to show mine as discrete data. I needed the spaces between bars and histograms do not have spaces between bars.